# htaccess deny from all gets apache server test page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have installed `zpanel` with `centos 6.3`.
Now what is the problem.

I have added domain `mydomain.com` and I have added blank `index.php` file. 
I added too `.htaccess` file with "deny from all" 
Now when I open the page in the browser, I get Apache 2 Test Page instead `403 Forbidden` 
But if I open `http://mydomain.com/index.php`, now I get 403 Forbidden.

I tried to edit the apache config file `Directoryindex` but there is no positive result. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Try adding `Order allow,deny`

Answer (score 4):

Try to disable the default Apache CentOS welcome page:

```
#
# This configuration file enables the default "Welcome"
# page if there is no default index page present for
# the root URL.  To disable the Welcome page, comment
# out all the lines below.
#
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/noindex.html
</LocationMatch>
```

Edit file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf` and comment everything. Simply removing the `welcome.conf` file (or renaming it as `.conf.disabled` for example) should do the trick too.

Then, reload apache configuration (`service httpd restart`) and things should work as expected.

Comment: This is exactly what the issue was for me, with apache2.4 on Amazon's flavor of linux. I had denys for a particular virtualhost, and *every* request I tried properly 403, except the 'naked' root. Turns out when I upgraded apache, it recreated that welcome.conf, which caused this behavior!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, when apache has been updated, the file welcome.conf has been created.
I've renamed it to disable it and now I get to see the Forbidden page for my Deny from all directives

Comment: This was published as an answer, but does not attempt to answer the question. Possibly it should be a comment.